# Can't encode to UTF-8 - json message - Python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, encoding

I have a problem with Python script. Everything works fine when im not using letters like: ą, ć, ź etc. Script using api to sending sms. In postman works too. Python 2.7.
I want encode to UTF-8 but i have: `{"timestamp":"2018-04-25T08:04:04.418+0000","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"JSON parse error: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0x9c\n`

My script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import httplib

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print("no agrs")
    print("arg1: number")
    print("arg2: sender")
    print("arg3  and next: message")
else:
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf8",
               "Authorization": 'Basic xxxx'}
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection('xxxx', 5050)
    message = ""
    for i in sys.argv[3:]:
        message = message + " " + i
        conn.request("POST", "/my/url/",
                     "{\"receiver\": \"" + sys.argv[1] + "\",\"sender\": \"" + str(sys.argv[2]) + "\", \"content\": \"" + str(message) + "\"}",
                     headers)
        response = conn.getresponse()
    print(response.status, response.reason)
    print(response.read())
    if response.status == 200:
        print("sent!")
    conn.close()
```

My error:

```
{"timestamp":"2018-04-25T08:53:25.834+0000","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"JSON parse error: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0x9c\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 66]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0x9c\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 66]\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 60] (through reference chain: my-method[\"content\"])","path":"path to my url"}
```

Comment: Where in your code do you use these characters? `sys.argv[3:]`?

Comment: in parameter when starting. I said u, script sending message to my number fine, but the probme is with characters: ąśćżźł etc.
Parameters looks like: sms.py 123456789 "sender" "message with characters like ąśćżźć"

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x9c in position 5: invalid start byte`

Comment: What system console do you use? What is your OS?

Comment: Now im using PyCharm and virtual Environment. Otherwise, im testing script in PowerShell and cmd and also works without that characters. OS: Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

Build JSON using the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module:

```
# coding=UTF-8

import sys
import json

s = sys.argv[1]
j = json.dumps({"message": s})
print j
```

Use it:

```
$ python2.7 so.py "message with characters like ąśćżźć"
```

Output:

```
{"message": "message with characters like \u0105\u015b\u0107\u017c\u017a\u0107"}
```